# API authentication in Angular

Tags: node.js, angular, oauth-2.0, webmethod, gigya

I have created angular application and implemented Gigya Authentication to authenticate user. I have API which is built in 3rd party cloud platform which support basic authentication and oAuth2.0 authentication. Currently I am calling API using basic auth, which is rejected by security testers, because it was exposing credentials in the request header. To solve that I would have implement oAuth in angular application. I am lost as of now how could I do that? Can someone help me to solve this?

Comment: does the gigya authentication passes successfully?

Comment: Yes, I have done it already.

Comment: are you using gigya to authenticate with your server as well or do you use a different kind of authentication?

Comment: Yes, I am using gigya to authenticate user.

Comment: can you add both the client side & server side code?